# Which parameter to use in relativistic Lagrangian mechanics?

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, coordinate-systems, time, covariance

According to Wikipedia the formulation of the [Relativistic Lagrangian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_Lagrangian_mechanics) is:

$$L = -mc\sqrt{g_{\alpha\beta}\dot{x}^{\alpha}\dot{x}^{\beta}}+L_I(x,\dot{x}).$$

However, I have read that using both coordinate time and proper time would be correct and I understand that. The problem comes when we use the proper time when dealing with the Euler-Lagrange equations, because I am not sure about whether the quantity $g_{\alpha\beta}\dot{x}^{\alpha}\dot{x}^{\beta}$ is conserved. I know that if we use the coordinate time $x^0$ as parameter of the Euler-Lagrange equations we can later manage to work out $\frac{dx^0}{d\tau}$ with the equation $$c^2 = g_{\alpha\beta}\frac{{dx}^{\alpha}}{d\tau}\frac{{dx}^{\beta}}{d\tau},$$ but I am not sure about whether this last equation would be met if we solved the equations with $\tau$ as our parameter, as the solutions would give us all the velocities with respect to $\tau$. So, can we use $\tau$ as out parameter so that $c^2 = g_{\alpha\beta}\frac{{dx}^{\alpha}}{d\tau}\frac{{dx}^{\beta}}{d\tau}$ is met? Supposing that there is an interaction term $L_I$.

Comment: Read where? Which page?

Comment: The reparameterization invariance is a non dynamical symmetry, which should be removed before solving E-L equation of motion. This note should be helpful: http://web.mit.edu/edbert/GR/gr5.pdf

Answer (score 2):

1. If the action is world-line (WL) reparametrization invariant, one can in principle use any WL parameter.
2. Note that the notion of [proper time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_time) (and more generally the notion of affine parametrization) refer to a specific curve/path. It does not make sense to use affine parametrization before applying the [stationary action principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary-action_principle), only afterwards (because neighboring virtual paths may have a different notion of affine parametrization).

Comment: When is an action world line reparametrisation invariable? I am supposing that the interacción term depends only on the coordinates (not velocuties).

Comment: One might have to use an [einbein](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/vielbein).